# Room Database Query for not equal

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to build a query for Room DB that finds all items except for a specific id. Well, no luck so far. I've tried both != and <> and the id is still coning through.

Query examples:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE _id!=:id AND team=:team")

@Query("SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE _id<>:id AND team=:team")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both of those forms of not-equals are shown as supported in [the SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html). Perhaps there is a bug in how you are testing the results. Or, perhaps `:id` is not the value that you think it is. You could also look at the code-generated implementation of your `@Dao` to confirm that Room has not screwed up the query somehow.

Comment: I'll go back and double check, but I'm pretty sure I'm passing in the right info. Thanks, JP

Answer (score 11):

Okay, so both != and <> do work for creating a Query where you want to exclude something that is not equal to the parameter that you're passing in. My issue was that I was running 2 separate queries concurrently and one of them need the id passed from the other. Changed the code to run one after the other finishes and all is good now.

Thanks again!

JP